# A few hours after a Google Meet finished, how can I view how long it lasted?

Tags: google-meet

I finished a meeting on Google Meet (website) a few hours ago. How can I view how long it lasted?

E.g., on Skype destop program, I can see how long meetings lasted:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is seems to be no way to view how long the meeting on Google Meet that finished a few hours ago lasted, unless if using Gsuite and that you're the admin in Gsuite, or if using Google education and that the meetings many attendees.

Reddit user [Cornerway](https://www.reddit.com/user/Cornerway) mentioned on [Reddit](https://redd.it/ovkn71):

> If you're admin, use the quality meet tool:
> https://support.google.com/a/answer/9204857?hl=en

Reddit user [Illogical_Fallacy](https://www.reddit.com/user/Illogical_Fallacy) mentioned on [Reddit](https://redd.it/ovkn71):

> If you had more than 5 (?) attendees, it should send you a meeting report shortly afterwards. I forget the exact number, but that's what they do for Google education